# How to describe directed mimics?

Tags: phrase-request, expressions, phrases

Is there a phrase for making a specific expression towards someone? How can I say something like:

> Jonas made his sexy face *towards the cashier?*
>
> Jonas *threw* his sexy face at  her?
>
> Jonas *gave her* a sexy face?

Comment: There are **faces** and **looks** and they are not the same. We make faces and give looks.  There is no such thing as "making a sexy face" though there is such a thing a "giving a sexy look".  A **face** is a caricature of the underlying emotion. For most people, I think, a caricature of sexiness would be a turn-off :)

Comment: Actually, there is no reason not to say "make a sexy face" as in to make a funny face. He made a sexy face for her. It could be read as comical.

Comment: Moreover, certain verbs that go with the noun **look**, on the other hand, cannot be used with *all* looks. She might **throw** him a nasty look, but she cannot throw him a sexy look. It's grammatical but its effect is farcical. So, the answer to your question would depend on what *specifically* you're trying to say. Are you wanting to describe a natural expression of emotion, or the facial caricature of it?  And what specifically is the underlying emotion? Is sexy just an example in your question, or is it central to your question?

Comment: There's plenty of reason to say, or not to say, "make a sexy face".  It comes down to what you're trying to say.  I assume the question goes beyond the merely grammatical.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, sexy was just an example, I was looking for the phrase *throwing a look*, thank you.

Comment: When looks are **thrown**, it is to give the onlooker a *quick* notice or warning.  A beckoning look is not one that typically gets "thrown", because such "come-hither" looks normally have duration  and nuance that make them unsuitable for throwing. https://tinyurl.com/ycklelcv

Comment: If you didn't mean sexy, but just any type of look, you should say that. The use of sexy in your question limits the answers. Nasty, funny, comical etc. allow for all sorts of other verbs....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- John **put on his sexy face** for the cashier.
- John **flashed the cashier a sexy smile**.
- John **gave the cashier a sexy look or smile**.
- John **glanced sexily** at the cashier.
- John's face looked sexy when he looked at her.
- John's turned his sexy face her way.

Those are off the top of my head. There are probably many more.

There's nothing wrong with "gave her a sexy face". But that might sound like he is being photographed.